# Can Rcpp::Function be NULL?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a cpp function which has an R function as one of its arguments like below:

```
void mycppfunction(SEXP x, Rcpp::Function func)
```

func can be a function, or it can be NULL. How can I implement this? If I do this:

```
void mycppfunction(SEXP x, Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::Function> func)
```

then, the line:

```
func(x)
```

gives me the error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::Function_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >) (SEXP)’
```

On the other hand, if I just define mycppfunction as:

```
void mycppfunction(SEXP x, Rcpp::Function func)
```

then running the code with a NULL value for func results in a segfault: "memory not mapped".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this but I would advise that you are careful about verifying the compatibility of the function passed in and the argument. Here's a small example, with *minimal* defensive code to ensure that `f` is a valid function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

typedef Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::Function> nullable_t;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP null_fun(Rcpp::NumericVector x, nullable_t f = R_NilValue) {
    if (f.isNotNull()) {
        return Rcpp::as<Rcpp::Function>(f)(x);
    }
    return Rcpp::wrap((double)Rcpp::sum(x));
}

/*** R

null_fun(1:5)
#[1] 15

null_fun(1:5, mean)
#[1] 3

null_fun(1:5, min)
#[1] 1

null_fun(1:5, max)
#[1] 5

*/
```

---

Note that the use of `SEXP` as a return type and the `Rcpp::wrap((double)...)` was just to quiet the compiler in this specific example, and won't necessarily apply to your use case(s).